# "exists?" method not working- trying to check if a user exists before saving to DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm new to Rails, and am trying to create a signup form for my site. It works fine, with one exception- it saves users to the database without checking first to see if they exist. How can I check to make sure a user exists before I save it?

User controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create 
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.exists?(:username) == false && @user.save(user_params)
      session[:id] = @user.id
      redirect_to posts_path
    else
      redirect_to '/signup'
    end
  end

  def edit

  end

  def update
  end

  def show
  end

  def destroy
  end

    private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :jabber_id, :password)
  end
end
```

Comment: How does your User model look like? How do you define that a user already exits – same email, same name?

Comment: Same username, though I might have the syntax wrong

Comment: You need to add a validation for uniqueness to your model as shown here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness

Also, add a unique index to your username column on the database level via a migration as Rails validations are not full proof due to race conditions.

Answer (score 5):

It does work, because the user's email address is not passed properly. That could be fixed by changing `@user.exists?(:username)` to `@user.exists?(params[:username])`.

But Ruby on Rails includes such validations, and you do not need to write them on your own. Use Rails present and uniqueness validations like this:

```
# in your user.rb
validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true
```

You might want to ignore upper and lower case:

```
# in your user.rb
validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```

And change your `create` method to this:

```
def create 
  @user = User.new(user_params)

  if @user.save 
    session[:id] = @user.id
    redirect_to posts_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Furthermore, I suggest having a unique index on the database level too:

```
# in a migration
add_index :users, :username, unique: true
```

Comment: May want to add `presence: true` as well.

Comment: Would also be beneficial to add an example of modifying their controller. With this, they'll no longer need the `exists?` check because it should raise a validation error when they try to save.

Answer (score 1):

Use like this in the model file such as

```
validates_uniqueness_of :username #=> or specify :email or :name etc...
```

Comment: The new form is `validates :username, uniqueness: true`. The old `validates_X` methods are still supported but aren't as flexible as the new ones.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, you should use model validation for something like this. However, here's why your code doesn't work.

The `exists?` method is to be used on the model class, not an instance of it for example:

```
Person.exists?(5)
Person.exists?(:name => "David")
```

The above is from the [exists? docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/exists%3F/class)

Answer (score 0):

As almost people suggested you above and this is the best way to use [uniqueness](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) validation.

But, If you want to give it a try with [exists?](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Base/exists%3F/class) 
You can do like,

> User.exists?(username: params[:username])